# segmentation fault: 11 in C++ code BST

Tags: c++, command, g++, binary-search-tree

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{

int data;
node *l,*r,*p;

 };

 int main(){

int i,n;

cout<<"Enter the number of nodes\n";
cin>>n;



i=1;


while(i<=n){

y=root;
x = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
cin>>x->data;



while(y!=NULL){


if(x->data < y->data){
parent = y;
y  =  y->l;
}


else{
parent = y;
y = y->r;
}



} 

if(root==NULL){
root=x;
}

else if(parent->data < x->data){
parent->r = x;
x->p = parent;

}
else{
parent->l = x;
x->p = parent;
}

i++;
}


return 0;
}
```

it is giving the segmentation error on iMac through the command windows using the g++ command, but  works fine on other IDE's (both online and offline IDE),i even tried the code on my fiends personal computer he has DEV c++ and it works fine on it,I also tried on an online IDE (websites:-codechef, etc and worked just fine ).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHcm9.png)

Comment: The code you show shouldn't even build, much less run to a crash. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please consider indenting your code properly so that it's readable.

Comment: Don’t use `malloc` in C++.

Comment: root is undeclared, even once declared (as in the comment to the answer below) it's uninitialised and therefore your code is going to crash **sometimes**.

Comment: Reaaly this isn't your real code (because it doesnt compile). Please post the **real** code otherwise your unlikely to get helpful answers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the decalration `node *x,*y,*root,*parent;` (as you stated in the comment to the other answer) then the variable `root` is unintialised. Therefore any attempt to use it is undefined behaviour and therefore your program might crash (or might not). What you are seeing (sometimes the program works and sometimes it doesn't) is very typical of uninitialised variables. Try this

```
node* root = NULL;
```

Comment: It's not even declared much less defined. Neither are the variables `parent`, `x` and probably more. Since the code as shown won't even build it's kind of pointless in attempting to post an answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the comments to the other answer the OP stated that he added the declarations. That's what I based my answer on.